# How to combine large .text files into a single .csv?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have several large .text files that I want to consolidate into one .csv file. However, each of the files is too large to import into Excel on its own, let alone all together.

I want to create and use pandas to analyze the data, but don't know how to get the files all in one place.

How would I go about reading the data directly into Python, or into Excel for a .csv file?

The data in question is the [2019-2020 Contributions by individuals](https://www.fec.gov/data/browse-data/?tab=bulk-data) file on the FEC's website.

*also I'm using a PC not a Mac

Comment: Just thought I'd suggest exploring the usage of dask (possibly instead of pandas ) considering the large size of the data and the processing time for tasks involved. 

https://pypi.org/project/dask/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to download all .zip files from the URL, combine them to one dataframe and save it to csv (this example uses `BeautifulSoup` to get all URLs of .zip files):

```
import pandas
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.fec.gov/data/browse-data/?tab=bulk-data'

names = [
'CAND_ID',
'CAND_NAME',
'CAND_ICI',
'PTY_CD',
'CAND_PTY_AFFILIATION',
'TTL_RECEIPTS',
'TRANS_FROM_AUTH',
'TTL_DISB',
'TRANS_TO_AUTH',
'COH_BOP',
'COH_COP',
'CAND_CONTRIB',
'CAND_LOANS',
'OTHER_LOANS',
'CAND_LOAN_REPAY',
'OTHER_LOAN_REPAY',
'DEBTS_OWED_BY',
'TTL_INDIV_CONTRIB',
'CAND_OFFICE_ST',
'CAND_OFFICE_DISTRICT',
'SPEC_ELECTION',
'PRIM_ELECTION',
'RUN_ELECTION',
'GEN_ELECTION',
'GEN_ELECTION_PRECENT',
'OTHER_POL_CMTE_CONTRIB',
'POL_PTY_CONTRIB',
'CVG_END_DT',
'INDIV_REFUNDS',
'CMTE_REFUNDS'
]

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html5lib')

df = pandas.DataFrame([], columns=names)

for a in soup.select_one('button:contains("All candidates")').find_next('ul').select('a'):
    zipfile_url = 'https://www.fec.gov' + a['href']
    zf = ZipFile(BytesIO(requests.get(zipfile_url).content))
    for item in zf.namelist():
        print("File in zip: " + item)
        if '.txt' in item:
            in_df = pandas.read_csv(zf.open(item), sep='|', header=None, names=names)
            df = df.append(in_df, ignore_index=True)
            print(df)

# `df` now includes 56928 rows of data, save it to csv
df.to_csv('candidates.csv', index=False)

# ...or make other operations on this dataframe
```

This prints:

```
File in zip: weball80.txt
         CAND_ID                CAND_NAME CAND_ICI PTY_CD CAND_PTY_AFFILIATION  TTL_RECEIPTS  ...  GEN_ELECTION_PRECENT  OTHER_POL_CMTE_CONTRIB  POL_PTY_CONTRIB  CVG_END_DT  INDIV_REFUNDS  CMTE_REFUNDS
0      H8AK00132           SHEIN, DIMITRI        C      1                  DEM          0.00  ...                   NaN                    0.00              0.0  09/30/2019           0.00           0.0
1      H6AK00045          YOUNG, DONALD E        I      2                  REP     571389.12  ...                   NaN               263194.63              0.0  09/30/2019           0.00        2000.0
2      H8AK01031      NELSON, THOMAS JOHN        C      2                  REP          0.00  ...                   NaN                    0.00              0.0  03/31/2019           0.00           0.0
3      H8AK00140            GALVIN, ALYSE        C      3                  IND     497774.71  ...                   NaN                  500.00              0.0  09/30/2019        1038.19           0.0
4      H0AL01097          AVERHART, JAMES        O      1                  DEM      22725.13  ...                   NaN                    0.00              0.0  09/30/2019           0.00           0.0
...          ...                      ...      ...    ...                  ...           ...  ...                   ...                     ...              ...         ...            ...           ...
56923  S2WY00018      HANSEN, CLIFFORD P.        C      2                  REP          0.00  ...                   NaN                    0.00              0.0  03/31/1979           0.00           0.0
56924  S6WY00043          WALLOP, MALCOLM        I      2                  REP      36352.00  ...                   NaN                    0.00              0.0  12/31/1980           0.00           0.0
56925  S8WY00015         BINFORD, HUGH L.        C      2                  REP     262047.00  ...                   NaN                    0.00              0.0  04/11/1980           0.00           0.0
56926  S8WY00023       SIMPSON, ALAN KOOI        I      2                  REP     150447.00  ...                   NaN                    0.00              0.0  12/31/1980           0.00           0.0
56927  S8WY00056  BARROWS, GORDON HENSLEY        C      2                  REP          0.00  ...                   NaN                    0.00              0.0  06/30/1979           0.00           0.0

[56928 rows x 30 columns]
```

And saves the data to `candidates.csv`.

---

EDIT: After reading your question, this snippet will load only Contributions from 2019-2020 and store them to one **big** .csv file:

```
import pandas
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.fec.gov/data/browse-data/?tab=bulk-data'

names = ['CMTE_ID','AMNDT_IND','RPT_TP','TRANSACTION_PGI','IMAGE_NUM','TRANSACTION_TP','ENTITY_TP','NAME','CITY','STATE','ZIP_CODE','EMPLOYER','OCCUPATION','TRANSACTION_DT','TRANSACTION_AMT','OTHER_ID','TRAN_ID','FILE_NUM','MEMO_CD','MEMO_TEXT','SUB_ID']

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html5lib')

df = pandas.DataFrame([], columns=names)
df.to_csv('contributions.csv', mode='w', index=False)

for a in soup.select_one('button:contains("Contributions by individuals")').find_next('ul').select('a:contains("2019–2020")'):
    zipfile_url = 'https://www.fec.gov' + a['href']
    zf = ZipFile(BytesIO(requests.get(zipfile_url).content))
    for item in zf.namelist():
        print("File in zip: " + item)
        if '.txt' in item:
            in_df = pandas.read_csv(zf.open(item), sep='|', header=None, names=names, low_memory=False)
            in_df.to_csv('contributions.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
            print(in_df)
```

The result is file `contributions.csv` with `14978701` rows.

After that I imported the data to Pandas (but it was close - I have 16GB of memory on my PC):

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('contributions.csv')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (3,5,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
            CMTE_ID AMNDT_IND RPT_TP TRANSACTION_PGI           IMAGE_NUM TRANSACTION_TP  ...   OTHER_ID         TRAN_ID FILE_NUM MEMO_CD                                MEMO_TEXT               SUB_ID
0         C00432906         T    TER           P2018  201901219143901218            22Y  ...        NaN     SB20A.55756  1305860     NaN                                      NaN  4021320191639407455
1         C00432906         T    TER           P2018  201901219143901218            22Y  ...        NaN     SB20A.55755  1305860     NaN                                      NaN  4021320191639407453
2         C00638478         T    TER           P2018  201901289144040159            15C  ...  H8CA39133         3703295  1307800     NaN  CONVERTING PRIMARY LOAN TO CONTRIBUTION  4021220191639267648
3         C00640870         T    TER           P2018  201901259144002482            15C  ...  H8FL07054     VTQYWHKD8W6  1307204     NaN         CONTRIBUTION FOR DEBT RETIREMENT  4021320191639532337
4         C00638478         T    TER           P2018  201901289144040158             15  ...        NaN         3703278  1307800     NaN                               CHECK LOST  4021220191639267645
...             ...       ...    ...             ...                 ...            ...  ...        ...             ...      ...     ...                                      ...                  ...
14939961  C00437244         N     M3               P  201903080300269078             15  ...        NaN  SA031819907833  1319643     NaN                                      NaN  2031820191645160755
14939962  C00365973         N     Q1               P  201904160300273926             15  ...        NaN   SA04191939261  1327732     NaN                                      NaN  2042220191647061196
14939963  C00365973         N     Q1               P  201904160300273926             15  ...        NaN   SA04191939262  1327732     NaN                                      NaN  2042220191647061197
14939964  C00365973         N     Q1               P  201904160300273926             15  ...        NaN   SA04191939263  1327732     NaN                                      NaN  2042220191647061198
14939965  C00365973         N     Q1               P  201904160300273927             15  ...        NaN   SA04191939274  1327732     NaN                                      NaN  2042220191647061199

[14939966 rows x 21 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple with Unix. I recommend to install a Unix like environment on your Windows PC and then use the `cat` command:

```
cat file1.text file2.text file99.text > new_file.csv
```

Or, combined with the download:

```
wget URL
unzip archive.zip
cd folder
cat *.text > all.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by first converting each file to csv and then concatenating them to form one final csv

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
csv_path = 'pathtonewcsvfolder'                    # use your path
all_files=os.listdir("path/to/textfiles")
urllib.request.urlretrieve("url/to/files", "all_files.zip")
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_all_files.zip, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(all_files)
x=0
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_fwf(filename)
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(csv_path,'log'+str(x)+'.csv'))
    x+=1
all_csv_files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(csv_path, "*.csv"))

converted_df=pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_csv_files), ignore_index=True)
converted_df.to_csv('final.csv')
```